# Can the active chrome tab be white with the dark theme?

Tags: google-chrome

I often have quite a few tabs open when I’m working. I use dark theme but for some reason the active tab is also dark which makes it almost impossible to find the active tab so I can move to the tab I need. I’ve looked at the default themes and the chrome style store but it’s just cat themes, cars, etc. Nothings actually useful. Is there a setting to just edit the active tab to be white without affecting the other color themes?